# Using CEA for monopropellants

Tags: calculation, performance, monopropellant

CEA (Chemical Equilibrium with Applications) calculates chemical equilibrium compositions and properties of complex mixtures and is the industry standard. Applications include assigned thermodynamic states, theoretical rocket performance, Chapman-Jouguet detonations, and shock-tube parameters for incident and reflected shocks.
I've only just begun to use CEA, and whilst I've found it to be very useful for bipropellants, monopropellants are a little weird.

Specifically, I was calculating the performance of 85% HTP monoporop at 15 bar and Cp/Ep of of 15, and found it to have a specific impulse of 1846 ms^-1 and a chamber temp. of 2069k. On [Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/h/h2o2.html#:%7E:text=Specific%20impulse%20sea%20level%3A%20117,the%20first%20American%20manned%20spacecraft.) however, I found the chamber temp to be ~910k and the ISP 1147 ms^-1. This dissonance is too great to attribute to varying Cp, expansion ratios or even HTP concentration. Is there a special mechanic for monopropellants, rather than merely selecting "none" in the oxidiser menu, have I made a blunder elsewhere in the propellant setup, or have I misunderstood something else entirely?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software, but the instructions https://cearun.grc.nasa.gov/intro.html do refer to monopropellants; perhaps a read through that might help. Documentation on the software is also available here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19950013764

Comment: Been using CEA since the 60s.  Used to work with the NASA developers: now gone.  Did work fror monopropellants.    Did you include the 15% water remainder in the fuel?  What enthalpy did you use?  Did you run rocket problem or other type problem?  Not familiar with cp/ep:  please explain.  tom kosvic

Comment: @tckosvic I think the OP means (chamber pressure) / (exit pressure) based on prior posts. i.e Pc / Pe

Comment: As soon as I see cp I think specific heat.

Comment: @tckosvic yeah, me too.